# Lucene term query in tis files

Tags: lucene

You know lucene firstly query the term in tii then point to tis,my question is that how the lucene filter fields.
for example:The tis file has 1 million terms,999 thousands terms belongs to content field,the other 1 thousand belongs to title field.
So If I query title:city, then Lucene will search the term city undistinguish fields?i.e firstly both searh the two fields terms (content and title )and then drop the content field.Or there are two tis files one for content field other for title field.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A field value alone makes no sense to Lucene. Terms consist of a value ("city") **and** a field name ("title", "content", ...).

If you search for "title:city", Lucene will only search for the "city" value for field name "title".

Comment: http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_0/fileformats.html#tii might help you understand how the .tii file is built

Comment: Exactly!My question just is:How does Lucene only search for the "city" value for field name "title"? I know the .tis file structure seems like this:city1(content),city2(content),city3(content),city1(title).So the lucene will search all of these terms than filter "title" or directly search title and how?
Thanks in advance

Comment: A query MUST specify a field name (even if the query parser might hide this fact) so Lucene only searches exactly one term.

Comment: I'm sorry Jpountz,I understand your mean,but I checked the lucene code can not find the exactly hitting the query field.

Comment: You should look at TermWeight.scorer (TermWeight is a Weight for a TermQuery) to see how Lucene looks up terms and Lucene40PostingsFormat and BlockTreeTermsReader/Writer to see the implementation details of the Fields/Terms enum.